# Where can I get the OEM driver for an IdeaPad A1-07?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got an IdeaPad A1-07 now and would like to debug an Android application. I'm using Win7 and eclipse and the Android documentation says that I have to install the OEM driver first, so I clicked the link for the Lenovo OEM driver and I got a chinese webpage and I really don't know what to download there. So I googled the driver but I wasn't successful ...

So, how can I get this driver? Did I miss something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click here:

[image]

Or simply check out [here](http://developer.lenovomm.com/developer/driverprogram.jsp). You will find the USB Driver download link on the right side.

Shamed on Lenovo, such a big company doesn't support global market.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've clicked where you told me to do and I've downloaded "LePhone2.0.msi", installed this file and tried to install the OEM driver, exactly how the Google documentation says. But my Win complains that it can't find the driver ...

Comment: @Binabik, the link referenced from Android dev website is probably for a different model, try this one from [here](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/hk/en/DriversDownLoads/APR_Driver_List.aspx?CategoryID=866611&OS=Windows%20XP#), which is named as A1 adb_driver.

Comment: thanks for your tip but the file cannot be downloaded. Google-seach for "a1 abd driver" lead to a tutorial how to root the device. This tutorial contains the correct driver: http://www.mediafire.com/?6v19365dkvc6k8r